# Statement giving unexpected results. is statement written wrong using :not?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, logic

I have 3 ids id==1  id==2 id==3 . each is a slideshow that has already been turned on on load. Using NOT I wish to turn Off the 2 slide shows not chosen by id.
this is not working. When ID 1 is chosen- both 1 and 2 turn off instead of 2 and 3. When ID 2 is chosen- both 1 and 2 turn off instead of 2 and 3. When ID 3 is chosen - both 1 and 3 turn off instead of 1 and 2.
 Is this a logic error or something to do with the slideshow code?

```
 if (id == 1){
     alert(id);
     $('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').data('nivoslider').stop(); }

 if (id== 2){ 
     alert(id);
     $('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').data('nivoslider').stop(); }

     if (id== 3) {
     alert(id);
    $('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').data('nivoslider').stop(); }
```

Hopefully, I have given enough information.
THank you for your help.

Comment: All `if` statements appear to begin with `$('div.nivoSlider:not(#c' + id + ')').` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Define "not working." What behavior are you seeing? Most likely the issue has something to do with the HTML you're dealing with. Could you create a code snippet that shows what you're seeing, complete with HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I have been sick. I so appreciate your looking. I cant think today to reply.  Each if statement is supposed to choose by id  the other 2 of sliders and turn them off.  so depending on which id is clicked. ie 1 then 2 and 3 need to turn off. id 2 chosen then 1 and 3 need to turn off. That is why I used the :not. I wrote on the comments above what is really happening instead of what I believe should be happening. I don't know how to put the code in fiddle because it would need the nivoslider css etc. I truly believe that it is something to do with the slider not the logic.

Comment: @guest271314  I am sorry, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Can include `html` be included at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected function could be simplified like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nivoSlider').click(function() {
      id = $(this).prop('id');
      $('div.nivoSlider:not(#' + id + ')').text('Stop now.');
      $('div#' + id + '').text(id);
    });
});
```

See demo at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv8bre6z/1/).

Comment: I will try this out also. Am sick at the moment. tks.

Answer (score 0):

I have done more debugging, It seems that my problem is not the logic.
I believe it to be something with the nivo-slider. I am going to post a question on the nivo-slider and see if anyone has any experience with this.
Thank you all for your answers.
geddeca